# i am new to ember js -- the reason of getting the following error

Tags: ember.js

> message":"Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on
>    while in state
>   root.deleted.inFlight. Called with {name: processing, oldValue: false,
>   originalValue: false, value: true}.

Comment: Provide relevant code which raising this issue ?

Comment: Please check Ember Documentation to understand the different states http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RootState.html you can´t try to change a property if the Model is already in delete state, most likely after you called model.deleteRecord(); without saving

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The best questions are those that are "minimal, complete and verifiable".  Please read this about asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking  You can edit your question to add more detail including your code.